# Why is my kivy program not calling the function from another class?

Tags: python-3.x, function, class, button, kivy

I think this is more of a python question than a kivy question.

`class Keyboard` is sharing a method from class `GUI`.  I created a `GUI` instance called `self.a` to connected the 2 classes in `class Keyboard`.  Also, I created a keyboard class instance, `self.key` in `class MainApp`.

When I use this method, `print ("Return button is pressed")` the "return" button was able to do the print statement.  I understand why it works.  When I use the `self.a.up()` in the method, the return button does not call the `up()` method from `class GUI`.  It's probably a small detail or a concept that I am missing.  This is not an error from the rest of the program.  Please help and thanks in advance. Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.modules import keybinding
from kivy.core.window import Window


class GUI(BoxLayout):
    main_display = ObjectProperty()
    text_input = ObjectProperty()


    def plus_1(self):
        self.value = int(self.main_display.text)
        self.main_display.text = str(self.value + 1)
        print (self.main_display.text)

    def minus_1(self):
        self.value = int(self.main_display.text)
        self.main_display.text = str(self.value - 1)


    def up(self):
        self.main_display.text = self.text_input.text
        self.text_input.text = ''

class Keyboard(Widget):

    def __init__(self,):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = GUI()

        self.keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        self.keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)

    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'enter':
            self.a.up()
#           print ("Return button is pressed")
        return True

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        key = Keyboard()
        return GUI()



if __name__=="__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it works fine but in another object that you can't see. The problem is that you show one object of `GUI` class on screen. And for the `Keyboard` class you have created another object that you can't see. So the solution is to use one object of `GUI` class and operate with it in both of `MainApp` and `Keyboard` classes. Something like:

```
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # here we create an object...
        self.gui = GUI()
        # ...send it to Keyboard class
        key = Keyboard(self.gui)
        # and return it
        return self.gui

class Keyboard(Widget):

    def __init__(self, gui):
        super().__init__()
        # and here we receive that object instead of creating new one
        self.a = gui
```

Comment: Hi @Lothric, thanks for the quick response.  I just tried your suggestions, and it gave me an error.       key = Keyboard(self.gui)
 TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.   also, what is the concept here that I can read more on?  thanks again.

Comment: @fishtang maybe you forgot to add argument `gui` to `__init__`, like `def __init__(self, gui)`. It's just OOP, no special concepts here.

Comment: hi @Lothric,  that is what I am struggling with.  I can understand some basic OOP, but even your solution, I would need to see if I can repeat it without any help.  Thanks again.