# python kivy, why my "enter" button with "on_keyboard_down" not working

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, methods, kivy

I am working on the same issue from my previous post.  Now I added screen manager, and I can switch to different pages.

[why is my kivy program not calling the function from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61134317/why-is-my-kivy-program-not-calling-the-function-from-another-class/61134851?noredirect=1#comment108155401_61134851)

I am still confused about OOP with GUIs, however I tried the following, and none of them worked.

I tried to add an instance of Screen 1() in the main app(), and it did nothing.  Then, I tried to add the contractor method init into Screen_1() and it says I don't have a build method. And few other ideas that didn't work at all.

Then I realized that there is no link between Screen_Manager() and Screen_1() because all of my methods are in Screen_1(), but the build method is returning Screen_Manager().  On my kv file, there is this code:

```
<Screen_Manager>:
    Screen_1:
    Screen_2:
```

isn't this is where the program "links" between the Screen_Manager() class to other classes?

if someone can help me understand what I am not understanding and help me correct my problem, it would help me to learn about kivy.  I understand, <> is like apply to rules, which has 2 widgets screen 1 and screen 2, and also have their own rules.

here is my main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.modules import keybinding
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Screen_1(Screen):

    main_display = ObjectProperty()
    text_input = ObjectProperty()

    def plus_1(self):
        self.value = int(self.main_display.text)
        self.main_display.text = str(self.value + 1)

    def minus_1(self):
        self.value = int(self.main_display.text)
        self.main_display.text = str(self.value - 1)

    def up(self):
        self.main_display.text = self.text_input.text
        self.text_input.text = ''

class Keyboard(Widget):

    def __init__(self, instance):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = instance

        self.keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        self.keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)

    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'enter':
            self.a.up()
        return True

class Screen_2(Screen):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = "Number Control App"
        self.sm = Screen_Manager()
        key = Keyboard(self.sm)
        return self.sm

if __name__=="__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

my kv file

```
<Screen_Manager>:
    Screen_1:
    Screen_2:

<Screen_1>:
    name: "first"
    main_display: display_1
    text_input: text_input_1

#------inherenting from BoxLayout
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
  #------begining of conent--
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 1
       #-nexted content------
            Label:
                id: display_1
                text: "0"
                font_size: "150sp"
                background_color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6,
    #--------
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .35
            orientation: "horizontal"
        #-nexted content------
            Button:
                text:  "-"
                font_size : "60sp"
                on_press: root.minus_1()
        #-nexted content------
            Button:
                text: "+"
                font_size : "35sp"
                background_color: (0, 1, 0, 1)
                on_press: root.plus_1()
    #--------
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: .15
            orientation: "horizontal"
        #-nexted content-------
            Button:
                text: "Config"
                size_hint_x: .25
                on_release:
                    root.manager.current = "second"
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
        #-nexted content-------
            TextInput:
                id: text_input_1
                size_hint_x: 1
                hint_text: "Enter your initial # here"
                multiline: False
        #-nexted content-------
            Button:
                text: "Up"
                size_hint_x: .25
                on_press: root.up()

<Screen_2>:
    name: "second"

    Button:
        text: "Go Back"
        on_press:
            app.root.current = "first"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"enter code here
```

thanks again for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question, but pressing `Enter` in your `TextInput` executed your code:

```
self.a.up()
```

but `a` in your `KeyBoard` is the `Screen_Manager` as set at the line:

```
    self.sm = Screen_Manager()
    key = Keyboard(self.sm)
```

and `Screen_Manager` has no `up` method. You can fix that by changing the code in your `KeyBoard` code to:

```
self.a.current_screen.up()
```

Note that this will only work when the current screen is `Screen_1`.

Comment: hi @John Anderson, thanks for the quick solution and taking the time for the guide.   Normally I post my questions 2am because after reading and getting frustrated, I probably don't think right by writing a concise question.  You solution worked, and I still need to understand why.  I am sort of in between beginner and intermediate python programmer, so there are many things that I am still not clear.  thanks again.

Comment: In your `build()` method of `MainApp`, the line `key = Keyboard(self.sm)` passes the `Screen_Manager` instance to the `KeyBoard` `__init__()` method. In that `__init__()` method, `self.a = instance` sets `self.a` to reference the `Screen_Manager`. But `Screen_Manager` does not have an `up()` method. The `up()` method is in `Screen_1`, so you can use the `current_screen` of `Screen_Manager` to access `Screen_1` (if it is the current screen). Then you can access the `up()` method as `self.a.current_screen.up()`.

Comment: Hi @John  Anderson, what if I want to make all the methods available to all the classes? Witin in the class, instead of through the build method? This is the part of OOP that I always no clear. Initially  I did try to  put an instance like self.sm = Screen_Manager() in Screen_1(), and on the build method only to Screen_Manager().  That didnt work.  That is really the solution I was looking for. Thanks for the conversation.

Comment: If you want common methods in different classes, you can define a base class that contains those methods. For example, `class BaseClass(Screen):` with those methods. Then define `class Screen_1(BaseClass):` and `class Screen_2(BaseClass):`.

Comment: Hi @John Anderson,  thanks for the base class idea.  I read a few tutorial on it and tried it with a simpler program.  I was able to get the inheritance going with a simple print statement from the base class, but the return key still not working. is there a way I can show you that code?  thanks.